# What is applescript for a worksheet.change event?

Tags: excel, applescript

I am new to `AppleScript`, but proficient in `vba`.
I would like to know what is the equivalent `applescript` for doing a `worksheet.change` event in `vba`.

To provide more detail, I have the following  vba code (simple but sweet for my purposes) that calculates a value in column F only after the user has input a number in column E. For clarity, the column headings are "Order Amount", "Amount Paid", "Balance Remaining" (D,E,F respectively). So if the order amount is $1000, the subsequent cells will remain blank until the user puts in a value under "amount paid", say $200. Then the "Balance remaining" automatically populates in column F.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 5 Then
ThisRow = Target.Row

If IsEmpty(Target) Then Target.Cells.Offset(0, 1) = ""

    If IsNumeric(Target) Then

        On Error Resume Next
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        Range("F" & ThisRow) = Range("D" & ThisRow) - Range("E" & ThisRow)

        Application.EnableEvents = True
        On Error GoTo 0

    End If
End If
End Sub
```

A work colleague wants me to add this to his excel on his mac, but I don't know how to write it in `applescript`. I have searched online extensively but can't find what I need, so any help would be very much appreciated. And the more detail the merrier.

Comment: Applescript in Excel does not seem to support events like this. However you know that Mac Excel supports VBA natively right? Try the Developer tab in the ribbon, if not enabled then follow here: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/visual_basic_editor2011.php

Comment: I did not know that mac excel supports vba - thank you! Unfortunately my friend has 2008 version, which seems to be the only version that does not support it. However he is willing to upgrade. Will I be able to simply copy/paste my vba code from my pc to his mac? Or is there likely to be some differences in syntax or command words?